# Get reference of text file resource

Tags: c#, resources

If I add a new text file to my project `regexCheck.txt` it's default build action is as Resource:

[image]

I know I will be able to retrieve the content of that text file if I set the option to copy to output dicectory = always then I will be able to find it on `workingDirectory\Macros\Header\regexCheck.txt`

I am just curious on how I will be able to retreive the content of that text file without having to output it to the working directory.

---

### Edit

For example relector is able to look at all the resources of my executable:
[image]

I know I could place the file in a `resource.resx` I am just curious to know how to extract resources from an exe

### Edit2

Doing something like:

```
        var _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = _assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()[0];
        var steam = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        var buffer = new byte[2048];
        steam.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        var text = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer).Replace("\0", "");
```

I managed to see the contents of my text file:

[image]

Comment: Here is a sample: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can using the way you've got the file attached to the project at the moment.

The other way to do it is to add a "Resources File" to the project.  (Project -> Add New Item... -> Resources File).  You can then add the text file in the resource file designer (Add Resource -> Add existing file...)

You'll end up with a project tree looking something like this:

```
Project
   |
   +-- Resources
   |      |
   |      +--  regexCheck.txt
   |
   +-- Resource.resx
   |      |
   |      +--  Resource.Designer.cs
```

In your code `Resource.regexCheck` is then a string containing the contents of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the build action from `Resource` to `Embeded Resource`

I was able to get the content by doing:

```
        var fileName = "regexCheck.txt";

        var currentNamespace = typeof(this).Namespace;  // if static class use name of class      
        var fullName = currentNamespace + "." + fileName;

        Func<string,Stream> getResStream =
            x => Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(x);

        using (Stream stream = getResStream(fullName))            
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))                
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();  // <------   Result should be the content of text file
```

the reason why that code words is because the class and the text file are on the same namespace (same directory and namespace)